# Regex for a URI / URL

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am currently searching through an HTML page for a specific link, at the moment I have a regex as follows that picks up a generic URI:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(https?|ftp|file)\://[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+(/[A-Za-z0-9\?\&\=;\+!'\(\)\*\-\._~%]*)*");
```

Although there are several links in the HTML so it picks out the first one, where as the link I want to extract is as follows:

```
http://*.*.com/dlp/*/*/*
```

How could this be achieved using a regex?

Comment: Any attempt at a general solution using regular expressions is going to fail. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/56778. But a search for "regex url" on this site will give you plenty of attempts that succeed to varying degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
http\://[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+\.com/dlp[A-Za-z0-9\.\-/]*
```

You may need to escape some characters again.

Comment: Hi , thanks, that gets only half of the uri, is there any way you can grab the rest of it?

Comment: That's almost it I am getting most of the uri, it justs doesnt pickup file-names at the end of the uri with the _ character